# Math alignment comment in ConTeXt not working as expected

Tags: math-mode, context

I'm trying to write some equations with comments in ConTeXt. According to http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf , the following example should span the whole text line. However, it seems not to work now (it adds spacing before text).

```
\startformula \startflalign
\NC\NC \NC 12(x-1) + 20(y-3) + 14(z-2) \NC = 0 \NR
\NC \text{which is same as } \NC\NC 6x + 10y + 7z \NC = 0 \NR
\stopflalign \stopformula
```

What I expect:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

How to avoid/remove undesired spacing below "Here is"? Otherwise, how to get the same result as the shown in the first picture?
EDIT: I meant the space between math formulas and text margins, not the spacing inside.

Comment: Keep in mind that the MyWay is 13 years old and a lot has changed since.

Comment: @HenriMenke... hmm..maybe it is time that I update it.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, a couple of things have changed.  In my MSc thesis from 2016, equations are also colliding now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is incorrect since it does not correctly answer the question. The answer seems to be that the stretching of the alignment doesn't work due to a now-solved bug in ConTeXt mkiv.

Something like the following?

```
\starttext
Here is some text
    \startformula
        \startalign [m=2, align={left,middle,right,left}, distance=0em plus 1 fil]
            \NC \NC \NC 12(x-1) + 20(y-3) + 14(z-2) \NC = 0 \NR
            \NC \text{which is same as } \NC \NC 6x + 10y + 7z \NC = 0 \NR
        \stopalign 
    \stopformula
\stoptext
```

which results in
[image: Result of using align]
See [the ConTeXt wiki](https://www.contextgarden.net/Multiline_equations).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I want to remove the space to the left of "which", not the space inside equations.

Comment: @JairoAraujo Sorry, changing answer to comment. The `1 fil` in the  `distance` keyword forces the `align`ment to be full width. I'm not sure why the sintax does not allow simply `1 fil` though.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of ConTeXt are you using? I've tried and it does not work on my PC.

Comment: @JairoAraujo I was using ConTeXt Live. I just checked and you are right, it doesn't work everywhere, at least not in my TeXlive distribution. The Live version is newer so I posit it will be fixed when TeXlive gets updated. Aditya made a comment about that on the newsletter in april but the thread remains empty. It might be a good idea to ask the question again here this time specifically asking why the "1 fil" glue isn't working in your version of ConTeXt and how best to work around this.

Comment: It works in updated ConTeXt and LMTX now.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the space around the equation using `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` keys for `setupformula`. Here is a complete example:

```
\definemathalignment
  [flalign]
  [
    m=2, 
    distance=5em plus 1 fil,
    align={right,left,right,left},
  ]

\setupformula[spacebefore={none}]

\showframe
\showgrid


\starttext

Here is some text
\startformula \startflalign
  \NC\NC \NC 12(x-1) + 20(y-3) + 14(z-2) \NC = 0 \NR
  \NC \text{which is same as } \NC\NC 6x + 10y + 7z \NC = 0 \NR
\stopflalign \stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I understood it as if it was the indentation of "which is same as" that was the problem.

Comment: Indeed, the spacebefore key isn't related at all with the problem I want to solve. My problem is the narrowing of the math alignment environment.